# Why setting the font size in XAML using my static property does not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fonts, datagrid

I'm trying to set the font size of my `Label` from my database, so I decided to store values in a static `Global` class, here is the definition:

```
public static class Globals
{   
    public static double mainScreenfontSize { get; set; }      
}
```

On `Application_Startup` I set the value:

```
Globals.mainScreenfontSize = ParametersController.GetFontSize();
```

And after that I'm trying to use it in my XAML, like this:

```
<Label FontSize="{x:Static local:Globals.mainScreenfontSize}" Content=" "/>
```

But somehow the font size is not applied.
Any kind of help would be great!

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. There should be something you didn't mention in your example.

Comment: @dymanoid, then I will post full code in a few mins, thanks for your help mate

Comment: Please don't post the **full** code. We need a [mcve]. **Minimal** is important.

Comment: @dymanoid I did not mean about full code about my project, I will post a full code about this stuffs where I'm setting font and retreiving value from database.. : )

Comment: How do you know that the FontSize is not applied when you don't set the Content property of the Label? Your code works. Make sure that ParametersController.GetFontSize returns the expected value or try with a hardcoded value.

Comment: Are you possibly setting the value *after* you've instanciated the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly works just fine for me:

```
public static class Globals
{
    static Globals()
    {
        mainScreenfontSize = 40.0;
    }

    public static double mainScreenfontSize { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
<Label FontSize="{x:Static local:Globals.mainScreenfontSize}" Content="Some big content"/>
```

So you should make sure that the `ParametersController.GetFontSize()` method returns the `double` value that you expect.

Try to temporarily set the `mainScreenfontSize` property to a hardcoded value like `40.0` and you should see that it works.

Comment: Hello man! Nice to see you around again! Your answers are allways cool!
And yes, you were right, there where I'm setting content somehow I hardcoded values, I don't know why, but thanks for pointing me that!